# Why am I directed to Null island?

Tags: openstreetmap, openlayers, wms

I am trying to overlay a geoserver map with projection EPSG:3021 with Google Streets and OpenStreetmap. Does anyone know why I keep getting to null island? (its supposed to be over the city of Lund, Sweden) And also why the Google street map does not show?

> 

```
<script>
//Defining projections
    var geographic = new OpenLayers.Projection("EPSG:3021");
    var mercator = new OpenLayers.Projection("EPSG:900913");

 //Defining bounds    
    var world = new OpenLayers.Bounds(13.12, 55.67, 13.27, 55.74).transform(
        geographic, mercator

    );
//Defining map center    
    var lund_center = new OpenLayers.LonLat(13.19, 55.71).transform(
        geographic, mercator
    );

    var options = {
        projection: mercator,
        displayProjection: geographic,
        units: "m",
        maxExtent: world,
        maxResolution: 156543.0399,

    };
//Defining main variables  
    var map = new OpenLayers.Map("map", options, { controls: [] });
    var osm = new OpenLayers.Layer.OSM();
    map.addLayer(osm);
    var gmap = new OpenLayers.Layer.Google("Google Streets");
map.addLayer(gmap);

//List of layers 
    var lund = new OpenLayers.Layer.WMS(
        "Stadsdelar",
        "http://localhost:8080/geoserver/wms",
        {layers: "lundpr:Stadsdelar", 
        transparent: true}
    );
    map.addLayer(lund);
    ///////////////////////////////////////
    var vagar = new OpenLayers.Layer.WMS(
        "vagar_alla",
        "http://localhost:8080/geoserver/wms",
        {
            layers: "lundpr:vagar_alla",
            transparent: "true",
            format: "image/png"
        },
        {isBaseLayer: false, visibility: true}
    );
         map.addLayer(vagar);
    ///////////////////////////////////////

//Map center and zoom
    map.setCenter(lund_center, 14);

//List of controls    
    map.addControl(new OpenLayers.Control.LayerSwitcher());
    map.addControl(new OpenLayers.Control.KeyboardDefaults());          
    map.addControl(new new OpenLayers.Control.Navigation());

//Coordinates of mouse position
    map.addControl(new OpenLayers.Control.MousePosition());
</script>
```

Comment: probably projection issue

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your problem is that the Centre of Lund is not at (13.19,55.71) in [epsg:3021](http://epsg.io/3021) as that projection is in metres. It might be there in [epsg:4326](http://epsg.io/4326) which is in degrees.

Also you should really use [epsg:3857](http://epsg.io/3857) instead of the unofficial epsg:900913.

Comment: How could I miss that? Huge thanks. Any clue why google street map wont show?